# Make connections with vertices

Tags: python, opengl, 3d

I have a function to generate the vertices of a sphere, but I don't know how I would also generate the edges/connections of the sphere. Does anyone have an idea of how I could accomplish this?

This is how I generate the sphere vertices:

```py
def uv_sphere_vertices(position, radius, stackcount : int, sectorcount : int):
    verts = []
    sectorstep = 2 * math.pi / sectorcount
    stackstep = math.pi / stackcount
    for num in range(stackcount):
        stackangle = math.pi / 2 - num * stackstep
        for num2 in range(sectorcount):
            sectorangle = num2 * sectorstep
            x = radius * math.cos(stackangle) * math.cos(sectorangle)
            y = radius * math.cos(stackangle) * math.sin(sectorangle)
            z = radius * math.sin(stackangle)
            verts.append([x,y,z])

    return verts
```

This is what I currently have:
[image: Points]

I need the connections to be the indexes of the vertices in the verts list. This is an example of what the connections need to be:

[image]

I've tried the way they did it in http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_sphere.html , but that didn't really work. I converted what was there to:

```py
    for num in range(stackcount):
        k1 = num * (sectorcount + 1)
        k2 = k1 + sectorcount + 1
        for num2 in range(sectorcount):
            if num != 0:
                edges.append([k1,k2,k1+1])
            if num != stackcount-1:
                edges.append([k1+1,k2,k2+1])

            k1 += 1
            k2 += 1
```

and got this result which is extremely laggy and not at all the desired result:
[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you mean.  A sphere does not have vertices or edges.  If you are defining your use case as a lattice of connected points on the sphere, an approximation of the surface, you have to define your desired grid for us.  That done, post your coding attempt and the results.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: Good explanation.  You show directed cycles; is that important?  I'll wait to see your coding attempt.

Comment: @Prune I have yet again, updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a fix. It turns out, I need to add one to the range values. Here is my final code:

```py
def uv_sphere_vertices(position, radius, stackcount : int, sectorcount : int):
    verts = []
    edges = []
    sectorstep = 2 * math.pi / sectorcount
    stackstep = math.pi / stackcount
    for num in range(stackcount+1):
        stackangle = math.pi / 2 - num * stackstep
        for num2 in range(sectorcount+1):
            sectorangle = num2 * sectorstep
            x = radius * math.cos(stackangle) * math.cos(sectorangle)
            y = radius * math.cos(stackangle) * math.sin(sectorangle)
            z = radius * math.sin(stackangle)
            verts.append([x,y,z])

    for num in range(stackcount):
        cstack = num * (sectorcount + 1)
        nstack = cstack + sectorcount + 1
        for num2 in range(sectorcount):
            if num != 0:
                edges.append([cstack, nstack, cstack + 1])
            if num != stackcount - 1:
                edges.append([cstack + 1, nstack, nstack + 1])

            cstack += 1
            nstack += 1

    return verts,edges
```